# i can't alias in Apache permission denied

Tags: javascript, chart.js, virtualhost

Why I can't alias in Apache permission denied?

Here is my code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName ayandap.com
        ServerAlias www.ayandap.com
        Alias /home /public_html/Login

        <Directory /public_html/Login>
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
          Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You virtual host configuration is incorrect. You don't have document root defined. Please refer below example configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName ayandap.com
    ServerAlias www.ayandap.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/Login

    Alias /home /var/www/public_html/Login

    <Directory /var/www/public_html/Login>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If it is still giving you errors, Try commenting out last two lines,

```
#ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
#CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```